# DB2 Application Development Client

Tags: db2

I've tried to get trough the following tutorial [Making Operating System Calls from SQL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze.html) but i got stuck when it asked me to install *"DB2 Application Development Client"*.

what is this *DB2 Application Development Client* ? does it have anything to do with DataStudio or ControlCenter ? and how can i get it from ?

EDIT: I've encounter a problem when the tutorial used the **sqludf.h** library, yet i can't find it on my installed system (i've installed *Control Center*).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names is DB2 have changed, and the article you are reading was written in 2003. Currently, you can download DB2 express-C than includes all the headers that you need, or you can also download a Data Server Client.

The express-C is the database with all the necessary elements to run DB2 locally.

The client is just the applications and files that you need to connect to an existing db2.

When you say Control Center, you should have the Data Server Client or any DB2, so you just have to look in the installed files to find the C header (normally in the 'include' directory)